# TableViewCell Nib error: loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set

Tags: swift, uitableview, xib

Trying to create a tableView cell xib, but am stuck with the error "loaded the nib but the view outlet was not set"

I have read many posts and most say to drag the "view" from File's Owner to the IB view.

However, if you notice from the images, I do not have a "view" as an option.  I have recreated a xib with the same results.  Maybe new in Swift 4.2.

Any help would be huge.

```
class VersionTVCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var  versionNumber: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var  versionDetail: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var  versionDate: UILabel!
}


class VersionTVC: UITableViewController {

    fileprivate var versions: Array<VersionModel> = [VersionModel]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.versions = AppDelegate.getRLDatabase().getVersion()

        tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "VersionTVCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "VersionCell")

        tableView.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 70
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
    {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "VersionCell", for: indexPath) as! VersionTVCell

        cell.versionNumber.text              =   self.versions[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].versionNumber
        cell.versionDetail.text              =   self.versions[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].versionDetail
        cell.versionDate.text                =   self.versions[(indexPath as NSIndexPath).row].versionDate

        return cell
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return self.versions.count
    }
}
```

Below are two screen shots, first from the cell and second from the File's Owner.

[image: First Screen shot]

[image: Second Screen shot]

I have tried linking from File's Owner to the labels as well. Did not help.

EDIT:
Adding my addSubView func:

```
@objc func loadVersions() {

    let newSubView = AddSubView.toVersions.getView()
    let blackBackground = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 65, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
    blackBackground.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent( 0.7)

    UIView.transition(with: self.view, duration: 0.3, options: UIView.AnimationOptions.transitionCrossDissolve,
                      animations: {self.view.addSubview(self.backgroundView)}, completion: nil)

    newSubView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: (self.view.frame.height) * 0.1, width: (self.view.frame.width) * 0.9, height: (self.view.frame.height) * 0.8)
    newSubView.layer.borderWidth = 1
    newSubView.layer.borderColor = UIColor.defaultDialogBorderColor().cgColor
    newSubView.layer.cornerRadius = 8.0
    newSubView.clipsToBounds = true
    self.view.addSubview(newSubView)
}
```

[image: Screenshot of VersionTVC]

Comment: On which line did the app crash?

Comment: VersionTVC loaded from xib or are you using storyboard?

Comment: @Vishal16, I am loading via subView.  I followed you below example and eliminated the view load error.  It now loads, but without any data.  I set a breakpoint on my VerisonTVC,  but now see it is not being called.

Comment: Are you using Storyboard?

Comment: @Vishal16, I also tried setting the file's owner to VersionTVC, but that did not help.

Comment: No, I have splitView and am loading into the DetailViewController as a subView.  Sorry I did not put that before, but I understand the subView portion and felt the issue is with this xib.

Comment: I want to see your VersionTVC screenshot. Can you please share?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186722/discussion-between-david-sanford-and-vishal16).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your code and it's just working fine.

Make sure you do not assign `VersionTVCell` of `UITableViewCell` class to file owner and not connecting `@IBOutlet` to xib

[image]

File Owner connections Inspector should look alike below image

[image]

Also, try deleting and reconnecting `@IBOutlet`

[image]

Tested example

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As per my understanding, all is correct in Code so Apply some step.

1) Make Sure Cell's class name assign with correct Name.

2) clean code with this command **Shift** + **option** + **command** + **k**.

3) If you not got any success with above step. Remove delegate and dataSource Outlets from the tableView UI and write manually after this line.

```
tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "VersionTVCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "VersionCell")
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
tableView.reloadData()
```